# When do you eat the charoset?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, passover, marror-bitter-herbs

During the seder, are you really not supposed have any charoset left on your maror when you eat it?  Why is this?  When do people actually get to eat the charoset?

Comment: Some eat it at Karpas

Answer (score 3):

When one eats the marror, he is obligated to dip it into charoses and then to shake off the charoses before eating it.  If the charoses remains on the marror, it would give off its sweet taste to the marror that is supposed to be bitter (Shulchan Aruch 475:1).

When one eats the korech, the Shulchan Aruch (ibid.) rules that one must follow the same procedure.  However, the Rema (ibid.) notes that the custom is not to do so.  Today, though, the general custom is to use charoses at korech as well (see Aruch HaShulchan 475:8, Mishnah Berurah 475:19).  While the Beis Yosef rules that one does not need to remove the charoses for the korech (see Kaf HaChaim 475:32), many poskim do require the charoses to be removed before eating the korech (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 119:7, Mishnah Berurah 475:17).  If one is careful about gebrochts, he should ensure that the charoses that he uses is dry and that it is removed before the marror comes in contact with the matzo (Siddur HaRav).

It is the custom in Belz to eat the leftover charoses at the Yom Tov daytime meals.

Comment: I guess I'm partly Belzer. (See my comment on the question.)

Comment: By the "Siddur HaRav" I assume you mean a source *other* than the siddur of the Baal HaTanya. I say this because (1) the siddur of the Baal HaTanya does not mention using "dry" charoses (whatever that might be) and (2) it specifically states that you should combine the matza and maror together and *then* dip it into the charoses. Moreover, (3) [according to the Baal HaTanya](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25077&st=&pgnum=187), wine and fruit juices are not a problem for *gebrokts*. So unless you added actual water to your *charoses*, there would be no reason to be concerned.

Comment: @Ahron, According to Rav Ovadia Yosef (Chazon Ovadia, page 97; Yalqut Yosef, Moadim pg 405), a small amount of charoses IS supposed to remain on the maror. The gemara (115b?) warns against losing the taste of the marror altogether; not having both tastes.


So it would seem that both Ashkenazim (as per the Rama you quoted) and Sepharadim taste charoses at some point in the seder.

See also the Kaf haChaim 475:32, who never has you shaking all the charoses off.

Maybe something to be folded into your answer?

Comment: @Ahron: Also, according to Rashi, the point of charoses is to take some of the sharpness out of the sap of the maror, for health reasons. Implying that while we do shake off charoses so as not to bury the taste of the maror, he expected you to actually have some left on the maror. I think this business of shaking it all off is a hypercorrection after a couple of generations ignored the SA's צריך לנער החרוסת מעליו altogether.

Answer (score 1):

For moror we are not supose to sweeten it with charoses hance the minhag of shaking of the charoses after diping the moror into it but you may have some charoses on the the moror.

As for Korech that dependes if you are carefull about gebrokes (not allowing any water to come into contact with your Matzah then the wine and water in the charosas will make your Korach gebrokes that is why those who are carfull about gebrokes wil make sure not to allow any charoses to remain on the moror and come into contact with the matzah.

Comment: Moishe, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for posting this information! Please consider registering your account by clicking on "register," above. This will give you access to all of mi.yodeya's features and will let you take full credit for all of your contributions.